# get-childitem : Cannot find path ' ' because it does not exist

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a script that can report on a folder size for a specified folder.

I keep getting this error after I put in the folder name and I know the folder exists.

Also if I don't get this error then I always get 0 MB.

```
get-childitem : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\downloads' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\powershell script.ps1:58 char:12
+ $folders = get-childitem $startfolder | where{$_.PSiscontainer -eq "T ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WINDOWS\system32\downloads:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Code

```
$startfolder = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the folder name:'

#check that input is not empty
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($startfolder)) {            
    Write-Host "folder name is NULL or EMPTY"            
} else {
    $folders = get-childitem $startfolder | where {$_.PSiscontainer -eq "True"}
    "folder Name`tfolder Size (MB)"
    foreach ($fol in $Folders) {
        $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $fol.fullname -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $size = "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB)
        "$($fol.name)`t$size"
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue is the running architecture of your PowerShell session and where that folder is located. Does c:\windows\syswow64\downloads return anything?

Answer (score -3):

so.. My power-shell is a bit terrible but I've got this working for me:

```
$startfolder = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the folder name:'

#check that input is not empty
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($startfolder)) {            
    Write-Host "folder name is NULL or EMPTY"            
}

else {
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $startfolder.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    $startfolder + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
}
```

the output is like:

```
test -- 2.65 MB
```

Comment: Your code is an improvement with respect to calculating the total size of all files, but it does not explain the OP's symptom (which probably came from a mistaken assumption about the current location or a mistyped path) and is actually a step backward: `$startfolder` is a _string_, yet you're trying to access a `.FullName` property, which doesn't exist. The OP's code is correct in this regard.